# Multilinear Principal Component in R

Tags: r, pca

I hope, i posted in сorrect section!
I learn the MPCA method and i have any questions, because i'm newby and just want to learn self. There is dataset, where values of vars are scale (sc) and nominal var(cat)
When i perform analysis i got the error.
I use `library rTensor`

```
library("openxlsx")
dat=read.xlsx("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/corr.xlsx")
View(dat)
mpca(dat, ranks=c(10,10), max_iter = 25, tol = 1e-05)

Error: is(tnsr, "Tensor") is not TRUE
```

What did i wrong? How use this method correctly?

[dat](https://www.sendspace.com/file/e66gvf)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the function `mpca()` accepts only `tnsr` type objects as inputs.
You have to convert your object `dat` to contain the data before in `matrix` format and after in `tensor` format.

Your current format is as follows:

```
class(dat)
[1] "data.frame"
```

So you can transform in this way:

```
dat <- as.matrix(dat)
dat <- as.tensor(dat)
class(dat)
[1] "Tensor"
attr(,"package")
[1] "rTensor"
```

And then you can use `mpca()` function!

Hope this helps!

Comment: what argument i must  enter in rank?

Comment: @schoolboy because the length of parameter ranks in the function mpca must be dat@num_modes-1.
In your case the vector of parameter ranks must have only 1 element

Comment: I thought like you, but: mpca(dat, ranks=10, max_iter = 25, tol = 1e-05)
  |======                                                                                                                                              |   4%
Error in list_mat[[i]] : subscript out of bounds. What does mean this error and how fix it. Thx for your help:)

Comment: @schoolboy The problem stems from the function `ttl()` contained in function `mpca`.
In function `ttl()` there is the parameter `ms` defined as `ms = 1:(num_modes - 1)`.
So considering that `num_modes` of your data is 2, your `ms()` is equal 1 and your list_mat is defined as `lapply(U_list[-num_modes], t)`, maybe some values in your data have a length > 1

Please accepts my answer as a solution to the problem ;-)

Comment: Yep) How to accept your answer as solution? and second question how to  define the number of num_modes in my dataset?)))

Comment: O! one moment how to define number of component using scree plot?

Comment: @schoolboy num_modes is parameter of function, defined by function Unfortunately I can not help you with this.
To accept my answer as solution you have to put the flag near the button to vote answer